# Squared covariance function of Gaussian process

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, hyperparameters, gaussian-process

This is my first attempt to write the covariance function. I have following values,

```
x = [-1.50 -1.0 -.75 -.40 -.25 0.00]; 
sf = 1.27;
ell = 1;
sn = 0.3;
```

The formula for squared exponential covariance function is
[image]

The matlab code for that I have written as  :

```
K = sf^2*exp(-0.5*(squareform(pdist(x)).^2)/ell^2)+(sn)^2*eye(Ntr,Ntr);
```

where `sf` is the signal standard deviation, `ell` the characteristic length scale, `sn` the noise standard deviation and `Ntr` the length of the training input data `x`.
But this giving me no result. Is there is any mistake in my coding ?

And once I calculate, I want to summarize into matrix form as shown below ,
[image]

if `x_ = 0.2` then how we can calculate :

a) `K_ =[k(x_,x1) k(x_,x2)..........k(x_,xn)]` and

b) `K__ = k(x_,x_)`

using matlab?

Comment: What do you mean by _"But this giving me no result"_?

Comment: I mean when I ran this code the K value is showing null So I think there is some minor mistake in my programming which I am not able to see !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtain the following error message:

```
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in untitled3 (line 7)
K = sf^2*exp(-0.5*(squareform(pdist(x)).^2)/ell^2)+(sn)^2*eye(Ntr,Ntr);
```

indicating that your matrix dimensions do not agree. If you evaluate the parts of your code separately, you will notice that `pdist(x)` returns a `1x0` vector. In the documentation of [`pdist`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) the expected format of `x` is explained:

> Rows of X correspond to observations, and columns correspond to
>   variables

So, instead of calculating `pdist(x)`, you should calculate it for the transpose of `x`, i.e. `pdist(x.')`:

```
K = sf^2*exp(-0.5*(squareform(pdist(x.')).^2)/ell^2)+(sn)^2*eye(Ntr,Ntr);
```

*As a conclusion, always read the error messages and documentation carefully, especially the expected format of your input arguments.*

**Subquestions**

To calculate `K` for a specific value of `x_` (`x'` in your mentioned formula), you can convert your given formula almost literally to MATLAB:

```
K_ = sf^2*exp(-0.5*(x-x_).^2/ell^2)+(sn)^2*(x == x_);
```

To calculate `K__`, you can use the formula above and setting `x = x_`, or you can simplify your formula to:

```
K__ = sf^2+sn^2;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that :)

Comment: I also have 2nd part of this question please have a look and if possible give some guidance

Comment: What is your second part? `K` is already a 6x6 matrix as requested.

Comment: Could you plz tell me the some concept behind this formula specially the last one for calculating K_ and u used sf and sn value ?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? `K_` or `K__`? If I made no mistake, it is the exact translation of your mathematical formulation to MATLAB code.

Comment: I mean how u translated the formula for K__ = k(x_,x_) with  K__ = sf^2+sn^2 ? I m not getting

Comment: If `x` equals `x_`, you take the exponential of zero, which is one. So the first term becomes `sf^2`. In the second term `x == x_` becomes one, so the second term becomes `sn^2`. You can also try to evaluate `K_` for `x == x_`, it will give you the same result as `K__`.